# HTML/JS sample log output issue

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a `HTML` log tool that displays on the same page and can be saved locally as a `.txt` notepad file.
It prints output but I need it to append each line instead of overwriting it. See screenshot:

[image]

Also, I can't figure out why the save button won't work. I'll add the code below for help please.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function display()
{
document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML = document.getElementById("fname").value; 
document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("lname").value; 
document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("pname").value; 
document.getElementById("pname").value = "";
document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML = document.getElementById("jname").value; 
document.getElementById("jname").value = "";
}
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value;
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
 
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 
    downloadLink.click();
}
 
function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
 
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
 
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}

 
</script type="text/javascript">

</head>

<body>
<table bgcolor="#0000FF" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company</td>
<td><input type="text" name=lname" id="lname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vendor</td>
<td><input type="text" name=pname" id="pname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description of Work</td>
<td><input type="text" name=jname" id="jname"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
<td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400px" align="center" border=0> 

<tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
<td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Vendor</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea1"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea2"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea3"></div></td>
</tr>

<table align="center">
<tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `the save button won't work` what happens (in the browser *developer* tools console) when you press it - any errors/messages/info/alerts etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that you assign `innerHTML` while you have to add table value to `innerHTML` like that:

```
document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML += document.getElementById("fname").value + "<br />";
```

And the second problem: I wrote `getValue` function to get content of each column.

Here is complete code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getValue() {
            var Items = [];
            var td1 = document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML;
            var td2 = document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML;
            var td3 = document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML;
            var td4 = document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML;
            Items.push(td1);
            Items.push(td2);
            Items.push(td3);
            Items.push(td4);
            console.log(Items);
            return Items;
        }

function display()
{
      document.getElementById("displayarea").innerHTML += document.getElementById("fname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea1").innerHTML += document.getElementById("lname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea2").innerHTML += document.getElementById("pname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("pname").value = "";
            document.getElementById("displayarea3").innerHTML += document.getElementById("jname").value + "<br />";
            document.getElementById("jname").value = "";
}
function saveTextAsFile()
{
    var textToSave = getValue();
    var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {type:"text/plain"});
    var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
    var fileNameToSaveAs = document.getElementById("inputFileNameToSaveAs").value;
 
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
    downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
    downloadLink.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
 
    downloadLink.click();
}
 
function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
 
function loadFileAsText()
{
    var fileToLoad = document.getElementById("fileToLoad").files[0];
 
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) 
    {
        var textFromFileLoaded = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("inputTextToSave").value = textFromFileLoaded;
    };
    fileReader.readAsText(fileToLoad, "UTF-8");
}

 
</script type="text/javascript">

</head>

<body>
<table bgcolor="#0000FF" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company</td>
<td><input type="text" name=lname" id="lname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Vendor</td>
<td><input type="text" name=pname" id="pname"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description of Work</td>
<td><input type="text" name=jname" id="jname"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp</td>
<td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="display()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="400px" align="center" border=0> 

<tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;">
<td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Vendor</b></td>
<td align="center"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
</tr> 
<tr>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea1"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea2"></div></td>
<td align="center"><div id="displayarea3"></div></td>
</tr>

<table align="center">
<tr>
        <td>Filename to Save As:</td>
        <td><input id="inputFileNameToSaveAs"></input></td>
        <td><button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save Text to File</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Alireza. For the second part (text file) I'm just trying to save the output of the "submit" button to a text file manually when I see many lines of results. It only needs the results after "submit" and I'm trying to save that to a notepad.txt file. Let me know if this helps. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer and now everything is ok. But for downloading file you need execute the code on your computer. It seems Stack snippet does not support download file